# What is the best way to upgrade all packages if you use a Desktop PC without a nobreak and with the possibility of a blackout happening?

Tags: upgrade

I use Synaptic to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04.

I am concerned on having problems in case of a blackout (that is not uncommon).

What I have been doing is to update at most about 20 packages at once, and always from the bigger to the smaller (I chose the Synaptic filter "Status/Installed(upgradable)"). But huge packages like more than 50MB, I update individually...

But I am still not sure how safe that is?

What is the worst thing that could happen? My machine stop booting (broken boot) in case blackout happens during an upgrade? Or is it fail proof?

And what I do is somewhat time-consuming... could it improve in some way (if there is no other better way)?

I always thought install scripts should/would continue after reboot automatically, but I never tried that (to suddenly turn off the machine) to see what happens, so?

Comment: You can get a UPS with a big battery, and not worry about blackouts.

Comment: The one I need/want is too pricey

Comment: Well, you've asked for the best, not the cheapest way. :~)

Comment: on a blackout even if your house has a UPS the next upstream router owned by your ISP may not so it may go down during the blackout so having a UPS may not be enough

Comment: @ScottStensland The idea is to download it all first, upgrade step by step offline :)

Comment: @mikewhatever "The best ... without a nobreak" xD

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what packages you're upgrading. If you're upgrading base system packages like dpkg, apt, python, grub with their dependencies, then their breaking could lead to serious issues.

You could try to download your upgrades first:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade --download-only
```

Then find reliable energy source and upgrade your system starting from the most important packages. Other packages like LibreOffice, gimp, DE and so on you could upgrade with possible blackouts. They more probably could be fixed by apt.

To be more specific, you could start with [ubuntu-minimal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-minimal) package which depends on some set of required system packages.

But better buy an UPS.

Comment: "dpkg, apt, python, grub" libstdc++ ? I wonder what could be that full critical packages list, but these are indeed a good start thx :). What I would end up doing is updating them individually to minimize the chance for problems. Btw the UPS I need is too pricey here. Yes, I always download them all first.

Comment: I just thought... I wonder if some day Ubuntu knowledgeable core team could mark these packages as *critical during upgrade*, in some way so we could update'm individually. Better would be a fail proof way to upgrade'm (in case it isn't fail proof as I wont test it :)). Creating a 15GB or more root image could be the best way I guess for now.